# Get matched element from the selectors used in jquery.is function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

```
$("#see1, #seeAlso1, .see").is(':checked')
```

The above code will return a boolean value. Is there any way to get first matched element which will return 'true'....?

Comment: `$("#see1, #seeAlso1, .see").filter(':checked:first')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$.each`:

```
function getFirstChecked() {
    var firstChecked = null;

    $("#see1, #seeAlso1, .see").each(function(this, index){
        var $this = $(this);

        if ($this.is(':checked')) {
            firstChecked = $this;
        }
    });

    return firstChecked;
}
```

**Edit:**

Better solution:

```
$("#see1, #seeAlso1, .see").filter(':checked').eq(0);
```

Comment: $("#see1, #seeAlso1, .see").filter(':checked').eq(0);   wroking

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `:checked` selector along with `first()`, to get the first found element in the page:

```
var $el = $("#see1:checked, #seeAlso1:checked, .see:checked").first();
```

Comment: I deleted my answer but I'm still unclear about the difference between  them. If possible please make a fiddle. thanks.